# RecyclerView issues with wrap_content

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have the following layout in my app. The card contains a `RecyclerView` to display all of the factors. I want this card to extend all the way to the word "Statistics", but not go past it, if there are many elements in the `RecyclerView`.

[image]

I have tried setting the height to `wrap_content` and also tried using `layout_weight` to get it to wrap properly, but it doesn't work as intended.

[image]

This is what my layout xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Title and subtitle-->
    <LinearLayout>
    ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/content_padding_top"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_padding_bottom"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/button_padding_end"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/button_padding_start"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/button_padding_top"
        android:text="@string/view_all"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"/>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Edit**

I have found a solution. I need to give the `RecyclerView` a `layout_weight` and also in the `<include>` tag i need to add a `layout_weight` and some `padding` to allow the shadow of the card to be displayed correctly.

*card.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Title and subtitle-->
        <LinearLayout>
        ...
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/content_padding_top"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_padding_bottom"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/button_padding_end"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/button_padding_start"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/button_padding_top"
            android:text="@string/view_all"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

*fragment.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout_main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <!-- Number input -->
        <TextView/>

        <LinearLayout>
        ...
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Range input -->
        <TextView/>

        <LinearLayout>
        ...
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Search status -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/search_results"
            layout="@layout/search_status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <!-- Statistics -->
        <LinearLayout>
        ...
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Bottom sheet -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        layout="@layout/bottom_sheet"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: It's obviously because parent layout has wrap content...

Comment: but i need it to wrap because this layout is included in the main fragment layout using `<include>`. So basically i need the card and the recyclerview to wrap. How can i achieve that?

Comment: child view should take as much space as parent and parent should take same space as children... It obviously doesn't make sense...